# play auto-test selenium test failed, no test-result TEST-{testname}.xml file generated

Tags: selenium, playframework, playframework-1.x

We have a Play (1.2.4) application which is auto-tested via our Teamcity server. The regular (JUnit) tests return a Test-{classname}.xml datafile in the /test-result/ directory when using

*play.bat auto-test*

but the selenium tests do not. They only generate a */test-result/{testname}.test.html.failed.html* or ...succes.html

This is annoying because i can not easily show which selenium test has failed from within Teamcity. I have to look at the logfiles/artifacts and see which failed.html file is present, open it and look at it which testcase has failed. Annoying!

How can i have play 1.2.4 generate a datafile/xml something which i can parse to see which selenium test has failed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i could find no information what so ever and no clue's how to get it done i wrote my own parsers of the Selenium HTML testresult files. I have released it on github with sourcecode under GPL: https://github.com/crunchie84/play-seleniumresults-parser